# awk and gawk with large integers and large powers of 2

Tags: awk, floating-point, integer

It was my understanding that both POSIX awk and GNU awk use [IEEE 754 double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for both integer and floats. (I know the `-M` switch is available on GNU awk for arbitrary precision integers. This question assumes without `-M` selected...)

This means that the max size of integer result with awk / gawk / perl (those without AUTOMATIC promotion to arbitrary precision integers) would be 53 bits since this is the [max size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values) integer that can fit in a IEEE 754 double. (At magnitudes greater than 2^53, you can no longer expect ±1 to work as it would with an integer but floating point arithmetic still works [within the limits](http://www.lahey.com/float.htm) of a IEEE double.)

It seems to be easily demonstrated.

These work as expected with correct results (to the last digit) on both awk and gawk:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{print 2**52-1}'
4503599627370495
$ gawk 'BEGIN{print 2**52+1}'
4503599627370497
$ gawk 'BEGIN{print 2**53-1}'
9007199254740991
```

This is off by 1 (and is what I would expect with 53 bit max integer):

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{print 2**53+1}'      # 9007199254740993 is the correct result
9007199254740992
```

But here is what I would *NOT* expect. With certain power of 2 values both awk and GNU awk perform integer arithmetic at far greater precision than is possible within 53 bits.

(On my system, `/usr/bin/awk` is MacOS POSIX awk; `gawk` is GNU awk.)

Consider these examples, all precise to the digit:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{print 2**230}'  # float result with awk...
1725436586697640946858688965569256363112777243042596638790631055949824

$ /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{print 2**99}'   # max that POSIX awk supports
633825300114114700748351602688
```

The precision of ±1 is not supported at these magnitudes but *limited* arithmetic operations with powers of 2 are supported. Again, precise to the digit:

```
$ /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{print 2**99-2**98}'
316912650057057350374175801344    

$ /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{print 2**99+2**98}'
950737950171172051122527404032

$ gawk 'BEGIN{print 2**55-968}'  # 2^55=36028797018963968
36028797018963000
```

I am speculating that awk and gawk have some sort of non standard way of recognizing that `2^N` is equivalent to `2<<N` and doing some limited math inside of that arena.

Any form of `[integer > 2] ^ Y` with the result being greater than 2^53 has a drop in precision that is expected. ie, 10^15 is the rough max integer for ±1 to be accurate since 10^16 requires 54 bits.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{print 10**15+1}'  # correct
1000000000000001

$ gawk 'BEGIN{print 10**16+1}'  # not correct
10000000000000000
```

This is correct in magnitude for 10**64 but only precise for the first 16 digits (which I would expect):

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{print 10**64}'
10000000000000001674705827425446886926697411428962669123675881472
# should be '1' + 64 '0'
# This is just a presentation issue of a value implying greater precision...
```

The [GNU document](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computer-Arithmetic.html) is not exactly *helpful* since it speaks of the max values for 64 bit unsigned and signed integers implying those are used somehow. But it is easy to demonstrate that with the exception of powers of 2, the max integer on gawk is `2**53`

Questions:

1. Am I correct that ALL integer calculations in awk / gawk are in fact IEEE doubles with max value of 2**53 for ±1? Is that documented somewhere?
2. If that is correct, what is happening with larger powers of 2?

(It would be nice if there were automatic switching to float format (the way Perl does) at that magnitude where there is a loss of precision btw.)

Comment: Your question would seem to be answered simply by the fact that IEEE-754 arithmetic works. In the IEEE-754 format, a finite number is represented by a 53-bit significand scaled by a power of two. 2\*\*53 is a power of two, so it is represented by a significand of 1 scaled by 2\*\*53. 2\*\*230 is a power of two, so it is represented by a significand of 1 scaled by 2\*\*230. When these are printed, they are converted from the IEEE-754 floating-point format to a decimal numeral. The code doing that conversion appears to do it correctly. All the arithmetic works as expected. What is confusing?

Comment: Specifically, what result different from what you observe would you expect?

Comment: Re “This means that the max size of integer result with awk / gawk / perl … would be 53 bits”: This is incorrect, or at least incorrectly phrased. The last consecutive integer that can be represented in IEEE-754 is 2\*\*53. But it is certainly not the maximum. 2\*\*53+2 can also be represented, having skipped 2\*\*53+1. There are many more integers larger than 2\*\*53 that can be represented.

Comment: Re “With certain power of 2 values both awk and GNU awk perform integer arithmetic at far greater precision than is possible within 53 bits.”: You seemed to be surprised at the decimal outputs. But the decimal output is not part of the floating-point arithmetic in `2**99`. In `2**99`, some exponentiation routine is called with arguments of 2 and 99, and it calculates the result and returns 2\*\*99. No great precision is required here; the result has a significand of 1, which requires only a single bit out of the 53 available, and an exponent of 99…

Comment: … When that number is output, some routine is called to convert it to decimal. That routine uses carefully designed algorithms and calculations to produce a decimal numeral. It is using more than just plain IEEE-754 arithmetic for its internal work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That is the answer I am looking for if you feel like writing it up.

Comment: Regarding "Am I correct that ALL integer calculations..." - per https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Floating-point-summary: `Most computer arithmetic is done using either integers or floating-point values. Standard awk uses double-precision floating-point values.`.

Comment: See also https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arithmetic-Ops where it defines Division: `Division; because all numbers in awk are floating-point numbers, the result is not rounded to an integer—‘3 / 4’ has the value 0.75. (It is a common mistake, especially for C programmers, to forget that all numbers in awk are floating point, and that division of integer-looking constants produces a real number, not an integer.)`

Comment: @dawg : absolutely no idea why u think `macOS nawk` has `2^99` cap ::: `nawk 'BEGIN { printf("%.f\n", ((_+=_^=_<_)-_^-(_^_^_+(_+_+_)^_))*_++^(++_^++_-!!_)) }'` ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Comment: `1.       179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368` ::::::: `2.      Darwin m1mx4CT 22.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.3.0: Mon Jan 30 20:38:37 PST 2023; root:xnu-8792.81.3~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64` :::::: `3.      awk version 20200816`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot speak to the numeric implementations used in particular versions of gawk or awk. This answer speaks to floating-point generally, particularly IEEE-754 binary formats.

Computing 2<sup>99</sup> for `2**99` and 2<sup>230</sup> for `2**230` are simply normal operations for floating-point arithmetic. Each is represented with a significand with one significant binary digit, 1, and an exponent of 99 or 230. Whatever routine is used to implement the exponentiation operation is presumably doing its job correctly. Since binary floating-point represents a number using a sign, a significand, and a scaling of two to some power, 2<sup>99</sup> and 2<sup>230</sup> are easily represented.

When these numbers are printed, some routine is called to convert them to decimal numerals. This routine also appears to be well implemented, producing correct output. Some work is required to do that conversion correctly, as implementing it with naïve arithmetic will introduce rounding errors that produce incorrect results. (Sometimes little engineering effort is given to conversion routines and they produce results accurate only to a limited number of significant decimal digits. This appears to be less common; correctly rounded implementations are more common now than they used to be.)

Apparent “loss of precision,” more accurately called “loss of accuracy” or “rounding errors,” occurs when results cannot be exactly implemented (such as 2<sup>53</sup>+1) or when floating-point operations are implemented without correct rounding. For 2<sup>99</sup> and 2<sup>230</sup>, no such loss is imposed by the floating-point format.

> This means that the max size of integer result with awk / gawk / perl… would be 53 bits… ”

This is incorrect, or at least incorrectly phrased. The last consecutive integer that can be represented in IEEE-754 64-bit binary is 2<sup>53</sup>. But it is certainly not the maximum. 2<sup>53</sup>+2 can also be represented, having skipped 2<sup>53</sup>+1. There are many more integers larger than 2<sup>53</sup> that can be represented.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE : statement on powers of 10 in 754 double :

> anectodally, even w/o bigint add-ons, if you're just looking for powers of 10 standalone, or using them to `mod ( % )` against powers of 2, it appears u can go up to 10^22.

```
jot 25 | gawk -be '$++NF = sprintf("%.f", 10^$1)' # same for mawk+nawk

{ … pruned smaller ones… }

13  10000000000000
14  100000000000000
15  1000000000000000
16  10000000000000000

17  100000000000000000
18  1000000000000000000
19  10000000000000000000
20  100000000000000000000

21  1000000000000000000000
22  10000000000000000000000 <---------

23  99999999999999991611392
24  999999999999999983222784
25  10000000000000000905969664
```

> `( 2 ^ x ) % ( 10 ^ 22 )`

```
   jot -w 'x=%d;y=22; print x,"=",y,"=",(2^x)%%(10^y),"\n"; ' - 3 1023 68 | 
   bc      | 
   mawk2 '$++NF = sprintf("\f\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b"\
                                        "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b%.f",
                   ( 2 ^ $1 ) % ( 10 ^ $2 ) )'    FS== OFS== |
   column -s= -t | gcat -n
```

All the powers of 2, even up to 1023, can directly obtain the exact modulo of `10 ^ 22` w/o needing specialized algorithms, string ops, or bigint packages, as confirmed by `gnu-bc`

```
 1  3     22  8                       
              8

 2  71    22  2361183241434822606848  
              2361183241434822606848

 3  139   22  2991196020261297061888  
              2991196020261297061888

 4  207   22  1983204197482918576128  
              1983204197482918576128

 5  275   22  7804340758912662765568  
              7804340758912662765568

 6  343   22  3047019946172856926208  
              3047019946172856926208

 7  411   22  729696200186866434048   
              729696200186866434048

 8  479   22  3987839644142653145088  
              3987839644142653145088

 9  547   22  1954520592778765795328  
              1954520592778765795328

10  615   22  5333860664072122400768  
              5333860664072122400768

11  683   22  3741475809259744657408  
              3741475809259744657408

12  751   22  1513586051123404341248  
              1513586051123404341248

13  819   22  2458937421726941708288  
              2458937421726941708288

14  887   22  8118143630040815894528  
              8118143630040815894528

15  955   22  3346307143437247315968  
              3346307143437247315968

16  1023  22  2417678164812112068608  
              2417678164812112068608
```

=============

not for *all* powers of 2.  as you said, It's based on limitations of `IEEE 754 double` format. The highest i can get it to spit out is `2^1023`.

`2^1024` results in INF unless you invoke bignum mode `-M`

That said, gap begins to jump past 2^53, and increases along the way (as you go further into so-called "sub-optimal" range. As for printing those out, `%d / %i is good for +/- 63-bits in gawk/mawk2`, and `%u up to unsigned 64-bits int` (but potentially imprecise other than exact powers of 2 once you're past 2^53).

***pre-mid-2020*** mawk 1.3.4 appears to be limited to 31/32-bits instead respectively. A change has been made around then to use 64-bit ints for `s/printf` caps.

Past those ranges, %.f is just about the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

one special case about powers of two -

if you want just 2^N-1 for powers up to 1023, a very clean sub() wil do the trick without having to physically go figure out what the last digit is :

```
sub(/[2468]$/, index("1:2:0:3", bits % 4), pow2str)
```

the last digit for positive integer powers of 2 have this repeat and predictable pattern when you take modulo against 4,

so using this specially crafted string, where the values exist at positions 7/3/1/5 (in descending modulo order), the string index itself is already exact last digit minus 1.

```
e.g. 2^719 : it goes 275. . . . 60288
                                    |                         |
719 % 4 = 3, located at position 7 of reference string "1:2:0:3",
```

so the regex replaces the final "8" with a "7", giving you exactly 2^N-1 for any gigantic integer power of 2.

if you already know how many bits this power of 2 is supposed to be, then this way is faster, otherwise, a substring replacement approach is definitely faster than running it through logarithmic functions.